# MySQL syntax error >.<

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Let's see if someone can answer this question before I can debug it. It's a syntax issue that I've tried changing. I commonly make this mistake, and I guess a definitive truth as to why I am doing it would help.

Thanks in advance!

The error this time:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'Andrew', 'West', '***@gmail.com',
'7*7 **', '', ' at line 14
```

The code used:

```
    $db_insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO catches (
        catch_affid,
        catch_firstname,
        catch_lastname,
        catch_email,
        catch_street1,
        catch_street2,
        catch_city,
        catch_state,
        catch_postalcode,
        catch_country,
        catch_contactid
    ) VALUES (
        $a,
        '$f',
        '$l',
        '$e',
        '$s1',
        '$s2',
        '$c',
        '$s',
        $p,
        '$cy',
        '$cid'
    )");
```

Comment: Show us the actual query that's being executed. Does `$a` need to be in quotes? Make sure that value is a number.

Comment: How about the other way round? You try it first and then if you can't we help you out! I don't think SO is hosting a competition on "who gets it first" like you propose :)

Comment: Hopefully that is no real mail address...

Comment: Sachleen, it did need to be in quotes.

Sujay.. it's not a competition. I was actually testing the speed of the site. This was my first post. Please get over yourself. 

rekire.. good looking out. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess something is wrong with the content of $a. Possibly NULL?

Comment: I wish I could vote this up. This was the right answer. To the "T".

$a is an integer though, so it was weird for me to encase it in '' but that worked. I think it's because sometimes it IS null, and sometimes it is simply not. It's supposed to be that way, but I just thought it weird I needed to encase an integer during setting values in the mysql.

Comment: This is weird: why "can't" you vote it up? :-? AFAIK you should be able to even accept it as an answer (which wouldn't be fair: Marc B arrived first).

Comment: Can't vote up with under 15 rep. :[

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten. Don't worry, it's the thought that counts :-)

Comment: Can vote it up now. I got enough rep. :)

Comment: I had forgotten to tell you, check out PDO functions; they should avoid you this kind of problems -- as well as many others. Bad queries will still not work, but they won't crash the script.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the actual end-product of your string operations (e.g. the real query), I'm guessing your `$a` is empty:

```
   ... ) VALUES (,'Andrew', ...
                 ^---$a being blank
```